# how to format JSON output from ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, format

i used the code below to generate JSON Data.

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult MarketList()
    {
        var mkt = db.GetDailyList();
        return Json(mkt, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Now it returns JSON in the format below;

```
[{"gainers":"CAP","date":"Dec  9 ","Open":30.87,"Close":32.41,"change":1.54},{"gainers":"AP","date":"Dec  9 ","Open":20.00,"Close":21.00,"change":1.00}]
```

what i want is to return data in the following JSON Format;

```
[{"dailygainers":{"gainers":"CAP","date":"Dec  9 ","Open":30.87,"Close":32.41,"change":1.54}},{"dailygainers":{"gainers":"AP","date":"Dec  9 ","Open":20.00,"Close":21.00,"change":1.00}}]
```

How can i do this using MVC 2 please?

Thanks

Comment: no joy gnome ..i changed the code to the following and the result was the same;         public JsonResult TopGainers()
        {

            IEnumerable<TopGainers> list = db.GetTopGainers();
            return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Answer (score 1):

but for anyone else who stumbles on this problem I had to do something similar and I used Linq to do it.

So you name the new var the name of the container and it should do it!

```
var formatedList = (new {dailygainers = db.GetDailyList()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Action to JsonResult. I use this snippet of what I've used in the past. Keep in mind I used this to dynamically populate a drop down list.

HomeController

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetSubjects(string term)
{
    IEnumerable<Textbook> subjects = _repository.GetSubjects(term);
    return Json(subjects, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

View

```
<p>
<label for="Subject">Subject</label>
<select name="Subject" id="Subject"></select>
</p>
```

jQuery

```
$("#Term").change(function () {
    var term = $("#Term > option:selected").attr("value");
    var items = "<option>Select</option>";
    $.getJSON(host + "/Home/GetSubjects/" + term, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, d) {
            items += "<option value='" + d.Subject + "'>" + d.Subject + "</option>";
        });
        $("#Subject").html(items);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks but that didnt help...i changed the code to use JsonResult but it still gave the same output.. The thing i noticed is each json entry has 'dailygainers' in front of it..that seems to be the main difference..where to i get to state this in code? thanks

Comment: I would look at the GetDailyList() method, modify it to return an enumerable list. Maybe change var mkt = db.GetDailyList(); to IEnumerable<dailygainers> list = db.GetDailyList();

Comment: no joy gnome ..i changed the code to the following and the result was the same; public JsonResult TopGainers() { IEnumerable<TopGainers> list = db.GetTopGainers(); return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); } –

Comment: sorry to bring back a dead thread alive. but i kinda did the same thing and to test the data i'm trying to show it on a alert window. the data that it's return is this [object Object] instead of the regular json form 1:test.